# Build failed with an exception

Tags: android, ionic3

Quando tento rodar no meu celular, surge a seguinte mensagem: [image: Mensagem de erro exibida no cmd]

Consegui rodar via Android Studio, porém o app fica muito lento

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veja se você já possui a chave **_JAVA_OPTIONS** com o valor **-Xms512M**

Painel de controle > Sistema > Avançado (tab) > Variáveis de ambiente > Variáveis de Sistema > Novo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Fiz o que cê falou, alguns downloads começaram a ser feitos, então eu pressuponho que deu certo kkk, Obrigado.

Comment: Deu certo? Se funcionou, marque a resposta como correta para que ajude outras pessoas com o mesmo problema!